# $_POST[$row['field'] <-- is this possible?

Tags: php, post, row, fetch

what i want to do here is 
1. fetch data from mysql db 
2. in a `<form action="post">`, i have a text field and the value of this will be the the `$row['name']` that i just fetch from mysql 
3. I want to be able to submit the form and echo what i just posted which would be the `$row['name']`, here is an example of what im trying to do but it doesnt work it just shows empty when i post it, yet when i fetch there is a stuff in it.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("my_db");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<input type="text" name="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['name'].'"><br>';  
//The line above puts the name of the document in the text area so the user can    just click post it
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="View documents"/>
</form>
```

The documents you selected are `<?php echo $_POST[$row['id']].' '.$_POST[$row['name']].'<br>'; ?>`

Im sorry if this makes no sence i guess what im asking in general is how can i put the `$row['name']` in a format that i can post it like  `$_post['name'] = $row['name']` <- this makes sence to me but when i post it the value is empty.

I am new to php and to stack overflow so thanks in advance!

Comment: `$_POST[$row['field']]` _is_ valid syntax. Remember to match your braces though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
echo '<input type="text" name="my_val" value="'.$row['name'].'"><br>';
```

then in your php code give like

```
$my_val = $_POST['my_val'];
echo $my_val;
```

for an array of values you can also give like

```
echo '<input type="text" name="my_val[]" value="'.$row['name'].'"><br>';
```

and in your php code give like

```
$my_vals = $_POST['my_val'];
print_r($my_vals);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reponse, the code worked perfectly! and i get this when i post it: `Array ( [0] =>Document1.doc,[1] =>Document2.doc)` is there any way to not display the `Array([0] =>)` part?

Comment: That means..??in general array should be like that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  :

```
echo '<input type="text" name="'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['name'].'"><br>';
```

Change to :

```
echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'"><br>';
```

In php you can access it using `$_POST['name']`

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone out there looking up this solution and need it for "SELECT" option ..do it like this:

```
echo "<select name='questions' class='form-control'>";
            echo "<option></option>";
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['q'] . "'>" . $row['q'] . "</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
```

and then in php code where the value will be passed

```
$q = $_POST['questions'];
```

It took me a while to figure this out..hopefully someone else doesn't have to go through this...